# describe() function over rows instead columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

As said in:
https://databricks.com/blog/2015/06/02/statistical-and-mathematical-functions-with-dataframes-in-spark.html

The `describe()` function works for each numerical column, It is possible to do it against rows? My DF size is `53` cols and `346,143` rows, so transpose is not an option. How can I do it?

I'm using Spark 2.11

Comment: So you want statistics (min, max, mean etc) over all columns of 1 row? Then just make a scala function (for Dataset) or UDF (DataFrame) which does the calculations you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do your own UDF. Either you make an separate UDF for each quantity or put everything in 1 UDF returning a complex result:

```
val df = Seq(
  (1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0)  
).toDF("x1","x2","x3","x4","x5")


val describe = udf(
  { xs : Seq[Double] => 

    val xmin = xs.min
    val xmax = xs.max
    val mean = xs.sum/xs.size.toDouble

    (xmin,xmax,mean)
  }
)

df
.withColumn("describe",describe(array("*")))
.withColumn("min",$"describe._1")
.withColumn("max",$"describe._2")
.withColumn("mean",$"describe._3")
.drop($"describe")
.show
```

gives:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+----+
| x1| x2| x3| x4| x5|min|max|mean|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+----+
|1.0|2.0|3.0|4.0|5.0|1.0|5.0| 3.0|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+----+
```

Comment: udf function supports only 11 columns and the OP says of 53 cols. You have to explain how to handle that 53 cols too.

Comment: @RameshMaharjan This also works for more than 11 columns (I tested that) because the UDF has only 1 argument

Comment: yes you are right. My mistake that I didn't notice that. ;) thanks